# What are the Specs of a 2011 Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-models

I have a 2011 Raspberry Pi, and after much searching on the internet I cannot seem to find the specs for it. Does anyone have any idea what the main difference between a prototype 2011 Raspberry Pi and a model B Raspberry Pi is?

Comment: Note that the fact that it says 2011 on the top of the board does not mean it was made then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory lists the revisions of the model B.  You can tell which production model of the B you have by counting the number of holes.

```
No holes - early model B
Two holes - later model B
Four holes - B+
```

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry model B (The first one) had only 256 MB of ram instead 512, but the same processor as the second, and it was without mounting holes.

Answer (score 0):

The specs for any raspberry pi model is on the following website. Just select the correct folder on the right side of the screen
https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-pcb-versions